# Searching the data from database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to search the data based on the month and year from database and the data should display on the view in grid view format.I have used two separate tables, one table for storing only month and year and another for other details and in this table i've used the reference key of month and years table. Now i need to fetch the data based on this reference key. Please help. I'm new ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Did you tried what I suggested in the answer to your previous same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194976/searching-the-data-based-on-the-selected-value-from-drop-downlist/23195513#23195513 You need to start by defining actions in controller and getting data from user, use selected data to filter records from table 2, return the collection and let grid display it.  Post specific question when u try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the "Building our Data Model Objects" topic on [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx) by Scott Gu. Plus [part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx) of the same series that talk about Linq to Sql (Entity Framework).